# Returning a shared pointer from a weak pointer return type

Tags: c++, c++11

Is this safe to do? Why is my IDE warning me about it?

```
std::weak_ptr<SomeClass> getStatus() 
{
    return _mStatus;
}
private:
std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> _mStatus = std::make_shared<SomeClass>();
```

My IDE states:

> Returning `std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>` from a function returning
>   `std::weak_ptr<SomeClass>` . Class `std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>` is not
>   compatible with class `std::weak_ptr<SomeClass>`

Is this safe or not? Should I ignore this warning? I get a crash somewhere here and I am thinking this might be a cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your IDE is wrong; the code is fine. There is an implicit conversion from `shared_ptr` to `weak_ptr`; returning a `shared_ptr` from a function whose return type is `weak_ptr` will just call the conversion. I just tested your code with three different compilers (gcc 8.3, msvc 2019, xcode 10) and they all made the conversion with no warnings. Returning a `weak_ptr` is perfectly safe because it will automatically become null if the original `shared_ptr` goes away, there's no danger of a dangling pointer here.

The error message seems to imply that your compiler believes the conversion is invalid; maybe you're using a very old version of the standard library? I don't remember whether there was ever a draft version of `weak_ptr` where the conversion from `shared_ptr` was explicit or required a function call.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that while the shared_ptr does reference counting, the weak_ptr doesn't. So, whether this is safe depends on how you are using it. The risk is that you return a weak_ptr to `_mStatus` and then the owning object (that has the shared_ptr reference to it) goes away, causing the ref-count to be zero and therefore the memory is freed but your weak_ptr reference to it is now referring to free'd memory causing chaos.  Now, weak_ptr has a protection that if you get the value from it and it has already been free'd it will give you a newly init'ed pointer (i.e. a null pointer).  But, if your caller is getting the weak_ptr and getting the pointer value from it (perhaps copying off to a primitive pointer type) and then the owning object goes away then that raw pointer value is now bogus.

Comment: The whole point of `std::weak_ptr` is that it can't be left dangling. When the owning `std::shared_ptr` releases its object, all `std::weak_ptr` referring to that object are automatically updated accordingly. You can't access an object from a `std:::weak_ptr` without first locking the `std::weak_ptr` to get a new `std::shared_ptr` for that object. You are just responsible for checking if that lock returns a valid object before using it.  What you say about raw pointers is true, but the point of using smart pointers like `std::shared_ptr` is to avoid storing raw pointers in the first place.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've just used the boost::shared_ptr before, so I may be wrong when it comes to the std::shared_ptr.  Is it not possible to get the raw pointer value out of a weak_ptr (or shared_ptr)? It may not be the intended pattern, but if it happens it could cause problems.  Know I've run into that before with the boost::shared_ptr.

Comment: "*Is it not possible to get the raw pointer value out of a weak_ptr (or shared_ptr)?*" - from `weak_ptr`, no (it must be locked to get a `shared_ptr` first), from `shared_ptr`, yes (via `shared_ptr::get()`).